# Get rid of Page number in "minipage"

Tags: page-numbering

I need help, i'm writing my thesis and i can't eliminate the page number in the "front page". Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,operight,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    %titlepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}

        \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
            \centering

            %University logo
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{UNIGE}

            \vspace{3cm}
            %Thesis title
            {\uppercase{\LARGE Tecniche di monitoraggio termoeconomiche per impianti a vapore di piccola taglia\par}}
            \vspace{3cm}
            %Author's name
            {\Large Tesista: Guglielmo Mantero\par}
            {\Large Relatore: Alberto Traverso\par}
            {\Large Correlatore: Alessandro Sorce\par}
            \vspace{3cm}
            %Degree
            {\Large Laurea Magistrale in Ingegneria Meccanica: Energia e Aeronautica\par}
            \vspace{2.5cm}
            %Date
            {\Large Dicembre 2015}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \clearpage

        \begin{center}
            \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
                \centering

                %University logo
                \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{UNIGE}

                \vspace{3cm}
                %Thesis title
                {\uppercase{\LARGE thermoeconomic monitoring techniques for small sized steam plants \par}}
                \vspace{3cm}
                %Author's name
                {\Large Candidate: Guglielmo Mantero\par}
                {\Large Supervisor: Alberto Traverso\par}
                {\Large Correlator: Alessandro Sorce\par}
                \vspace{3cm}
                %Degree
                {\Large Master Degree in Mechanical Engineering:  Energy and Aeronautics\par}
                \vspace{2.5cm}
                %Date
                {\Large December 2015}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{center}
        \clearpage


\end{document}
```

I tried with `\thispagestyle{empty}` but it does not work. I always get the page number on the top right corner. Can you help?

Comment: the first page is white then i have a second and a third page with the two minipages (that are both numered)

Comment: yes the first one is blank (without number), the second has number 2 and the third number 3. No i would like to have just 2 pages with two minipages (both without number)

Comment: minipages don't have page numbers.  the page number is being set on the page where the minipage is placed.  (the answers provided are good, but leave out this useful bit of information.)

Answer (score 4):

I guess, you mean the page number on your second page (repeating the first title page)?

Well, `\thispagestyle{empty}` works for only one page.  Just repeat it after the `\clearpage` (see `<===============` in code).

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,operight,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

%titlepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}

        \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
            \centering

            %University logo
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{UNIGE}

            \vspace{3cm}
            %Thesis title
            {\uppercase{\LARGE Tecniche di monitoraggio termoeconomiche per impianti a vapore di piccola taglia\par}}
            \vspace{3cm}
            %Author's name
            {\Large Tesista: Guglielmo Mantero\par}
            {\Large Relatore: Alberto Traverso\par}
            {\Large Correlatore: Alessandro Sorce\par}
            \vspace{3cm}
            %Degree
            {\Large Laurea Magistrale in Ingegneria Meccanica: Energia e Aeronautica\par}
            \vspace{2.5cm}
            %Date
            {\Large Dicembre 2015}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}

    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{empty} % <========================================
        \begin{center}
            \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
                \centering

                %University logo
                \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{UNIGE}

                \vspace{3cm}
                %Thesis title
                {\uppercase{\LARGE thermoeconomic monitoring techniques for small sized steam plants \par}}
                \vspace{3cm}
                %Author's name
                {\Large Candidate: Guglielmo Mantero\par}
                {\Large Supervisor: Alberto Traverso\par}
                {\Large Correlator: Alessandro Sorce\par}
                \vspace{3cm}
                %Degree
                {\Large Master Degree in Mechanical Engineering:  Energy and Aeronautics\par}
                \vspace{2.5cm}
                %Date
                {\Large December 2015}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{center}
        \clearpage


\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

I just want to add a comment of @barbarabeeton:  "minipages don't have page numbers. The page number is being set on the page where the minipage is placed."

You can use one or more separate minipages and place them on a page in your document (if they fit the page, of course!). Minipages can have own footnotes, paragraphs, arrays etc., but no floats or page numbers ...

So your title of your question is missleading.  And that is the reason, why you have to use `\thispagestyle{empty}` outside your used minipage(s).